# Using Microsoft Graph Communications API to monitor a users Teams calls

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I am trying to create an application for realtime monitoring of calls in MS Teams. I tried to use a bot but did not manage anything other than monitoring calls to/from the bot. I would like to get an event where an user starts a new call or is ending a call.
Is it possible to use Microsoft Graph Communications API for monitoring like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with the standard graph APIs, but the new Policy Recording (previously Compliance recording) APIs should be able to do this.  You'll get a bot event when a monitored user gets/receives a call.  You can't do much with it besides record, but have a look at the sample here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/PolicyRecordingBot